# CMake compile swift project

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, compilation, cmake

I've tried playing with the idea to compile my mixed swift/objective-c/c++ based project using CMake. So as a starter, I went to [SwiftMix](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/tree/master/Tests/SwiftMix) example and run the following CMakeList.txt file :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(SwiftMix C Swift)

add_executable(SwiftMix CMain.c ObjCMain.m SwiftMain.swift ObjC-Swift.h)
set_property(TARGET SwiftMix PROPERTY XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER "ObjC-Swift.h")
```

After running cmake on the file above, I got the following error :

`CMake Error: CMAKE_Swift_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage`

However, it looks like inside CMake installation (version 3.9.1), there's a file/files which handle the swift support and define the missing variable from the error message :

`/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.9.1//share/cmake/Modules/CMakeSwiftCompiler.cmake.in`

Any idea how can I change the "CMakeLists.txt" to support swift ?

Answer (score -2):

First, Swift language not supported by "Unix Makefiles" generator. So, you have to use cmake -G Xcode .
Then, generator the Xcode project, if it does not work, you can try the sudo xcode-select --reset or upgrade your cmake version.
Final, try cmake -G Xcode . again.